# Why does the ASP.NET MVC4 new demo internet application initialize membership in an action filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking at the latest ASP.NET MVC4 internet application that uses SimpleMembership. I see the following that's placed inside an action filter:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }
```

Can someone tell me why it's coded this way? Why not just put a call to the initialization code in global.asax which is run once every app start? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it is placed there. But, if you want your `Membership` functions execute well , then you will need to call that method once.So, if you call any `Membership` related method anywhere except in `AccountController`, then make sure you have first called `LazyInitializer`.

I believe the template used an attribute for database initialization so that the non-authenticated portions of the site would still work if the initialization failed.

For most practical purposes, it's best to just have this done in the `Application_Start`.

Comment: @Melina yeah I meant `Application_Start()` that is in `Global.asax`. My bad...:)

Answer (score 0):

Putting the initialisation in an ActionFilter is a bit nicer for code reuse.  You could put your controller in its own assembly (assuming you're using a DI container to find your controllers) and then reuse it within multiple projects.  Since the initialisation is done on a filter of the controller, you wouldn't need to ensure it's registered in each project, since it will just get picked up automatically.

Another reason is lazy initialisation - if your site is mostly anonymous, then you don't need to have this initialisation routine called.  Granted it probably doesn't do much, but it means that an initial loading delay only occurs on a page which requires logging in, rather than your home page, for example.

Comment: thanks for your advice. When you said "don't have to have this initialization routine called"  Can you explain a bit more. I thought it would only be called on application start. Is that not just on start up and just a one time thing that might happen only when I upload a new copy of code and start it up for the first time?

Comment: You only need to initialise the membership data when the account controller is used.  If your Home controller doesn't need the user to be logged in, visiting the home page when the app isn't running won't cause the membership initialisation code to run.  The first person to hit the Account controller pages will trigger this instead.